# Upgrade Phonegap 0.9.6 in ios5

Tags: iphone, cordova

We developed Iphone app in ios4.2 with phonegap 0.9.3.
Now we trying to udpgrade Phonegap version to 0.9.6 in ios5.

Problem is we installed ios5 and phonegap 0.9.6 but it shows PhoneGapCommand obj undefined.
please help me to come over from this issue.

Advance thanks

Comment: Two things.. One, iOS5 is under NDA so it will be difficult to get much help in a public forums. Perhaps try the Apple developer forums. There might be some PhoneGap types there. Two, Upgrading PhoneGap to 0.9.6 to work in an as-yet unreleased iOS seems counter productive when PhoneGap is now at version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Migrate PhoneGapCommand to PGPlugin.
```

Phonegap have a very loose change strategy: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/33313613/Changelog.

To fix this problem you just need to rename all references of PhoneGapCommand to PGPlugin

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after including the json2.js file? (Phonegap need it now...)

Comment: It was an answer, but not well written I guess. Sorry about that